# Unexpected behaviour in threadsafe class

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I try to make a thread safe class which allows to follow the scan of something. My class is:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ScanInProgress {

    private final Integer scanId;
    private final int nbScans;

    private AtomicInteger nbResponses = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private AtomicInteger nbErrors = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public ScanInProgress(Integer scanId, int nbSites) {
        this.scanId = scanId;
        this.nbScans = nbSites;
    }

    public Integer getScanId() {
        return scanId;
    }

    public boolean addSuccess() {
        addResponse();
        return isDone();
    }

    public boolean addError() {
        addResponse();
        nbErrors.incrementAndGet();
        return isDone();
    }

    private void addResponse() {
        nbResponses.incrementAndGet();
    }

    private boolean isDone() {
        return nbResponses.get() == nbScans;
    }

    public int getNbSuccesses() {
        return nbResponses.get() - nbErrors.get();
    }

    public int getNbResponses() {
        return nbResponses.get();
    }

}
```

I have the following unit tests class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ScanInProgressTest {

    @Test
    public void testConcurrency() throws Exception {

        // given
        Integer scanId = 1;
        int nbScans = 500_000;
        ScanInProgress scanInProgress = new ScanInProgress(scanId, nbScans);

        // when
        for (int i = 1; i <= nbScans / 2; i++) {
            new AddError(scanInProgress).start();
            new AddSuccess(scanInProgress).start();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        // then
        assertEquals(nbScans, scanInProgress.getNbResponses());
        assertEquals(nbScans / 2, scanInProgress.getNbSuccesses());

    }

    private class AddError extends Thread {

        private ScanInProgress scanInProgress;

        public AddError(ScanInProgress scanInProgress) {
            this.scanInProgress = scanInProgress;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int before = scanInProgress.getNbResponses();
            scanInProgress.addError();
            int after = scanInProgress.getNbResponses();
            assertTrue("Add error: before=" + before + ", after=" + after, before < after);
        }

    }

    private class AddSuccess extends Thread {

        private ScanInProgress scanInProgress;

        public AddSuccess(ScanInProgress scanInProgress) {
            this.scanInProgress = scanInProgress;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int beforeResponses = scanInProgress.getNbResponses();
            int beforeSuccesses = scanInProgress.getNbSuccesses();
            scanInProgress.addSuccess();
            int afterResponses = scanInProgress.getNbResponses();
            int afterSuccesses = scanInProgress.getNbSuccesses();
            assertTrue("Add success responses: before=" + beforeResponses + ", after=" + afterResponses, beforeResponses < afterResponses);
            assertTrue("Add success successes: before=" + beforeSuccesses + ", after=" + afterSuccesses, beforeSuccesses < afterSuccesses);
        }

    }

}
```

When I run my test I can see regularly this error in logs:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14723" java.lang.AssertionError: Add success successes: before=7362, after=7362
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
```

The assertion lets me think that when I call the method `scanInProgress.addSuccess()` and then `scanInProgress.getNbSuccesses()`, the instruction in first method `nbResponses.incrementAndGet()` is not yet acknowledged whereas the instruction in second method `nbResponses.get()` returns something.

What can I do to correct this ?

Comment: I think you need to create a simpler example of your code so you can see what the real problem is. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your fields are atomic but you provide methods that are not. Thus they are not per se thread safe. But even if they were, calling two methods makes you synchronize again. So you have two issues here: You are not thread-safe when you believe you are and your test for thread safety is invalid, too.

Comment: Yes, that would happen when two threads are updating your counters and one of them is still in the middle (added to response, but not yet to errors). But why is that a problem? If you need consistent snapsnots of both counters at a given time, then you need to add synchronization. Ideally, you can avoid needing to do that (your "isDone" should still work for example, as it only needs one counter).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I unsterstand the problem I think you need to use locks. Before you get or set an variable you need to aquire a lock. This way a variable can't be set and read at the same time. You get something like the code below.

```
public final static Object LOCK = new Object();

private int yourvariable;

public void setVar(int var){
    synchronized(LOCK){
        yourvariable = var;
    }
}

public int getVar(){
    int toReturn;
    synchronized(LOCK){
        toReturn = yourvariable;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

note: If your ScanInProgessClass is the only the ScanInProgressClass class, you can use `this` instead of a LOCK object.

Comment: That still synchronizes only on the individual counter level, so it does not seem to improve over the current solution (AtomicInteger already takes care of that).